# Determine the UI library that a particular website is using

Tags: html, css

I am starting to build my own website using the Django framework. It has become apparent that in order to make quick progress I will have to use some form of external library to handle most of my HTML/CSS/Javascript, for example, https://materializecss.com

I have begun investigating different websites to see what works and what doesn't and I was wondering if there is a quick way to identify what UI library a particular website is using.

Chrome's 'inspect' tool doesn't really help me because I get lost with so much HTML.

For example, this website https://www.moneyunder30.com/category/banking apparently uses https://materializecss.com, is there a general place hidden deep in the HTML where I could look to find this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a pretty cool Chrome extension called [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=en)